# How to create custom print method for S4 object in R

Tags: r, r-s4, r-s3

I created a custom class and print method:

```
#custom class
myClass <- setClass(Class = "myClass",
                    slots = c(a = "character"),
                    prototype = list(a = character()))
#custom print method
print.myClass <- function(theObject){
    print("2")
}
#create a variable for testing
test <- myClass(a = "1")
```

It works fine if I use `print(test)`:

```
> print(test)
[1] "2"
```

But if I just run the variable itself without `print()`, it displays differently.

```
> test
An object of class "myClass"
Slot "a":
[1] "1"
```

What should I do to make the custom print method works the same way when I run it without using `print()`?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just figured it out by myself. For S4 objects, you need to use `show()`.

It works if I use this:

```
setMethod(f = "show",
          signature = "myClass",
          definition = function(object){
              print("2")
          })
```

it works:

```
> test
[1] "2"
```